# How to prevent the same requests to server?

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have controller and service with cached value.

```js
app.service('nameService', ['$q','$http', function($q, $http){
    var that = this;

    that.name = null;

    this.index = function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if (that.name !== null) {

            // fired cahed value
            console.log('cashed');

            deferred.resolve(that.name);

        } else {
            $http.get('/api/name').success(
                function(response) {

                    // fired request to server
                    console.log('server');

                    that.name = response.name;
                    deferred.resolve(that.name);

                }
            );
        }

        return deferred.promise;
}]);
```

When requests in controller send with interval like

```js
app.controller('nameCtr', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'nameService'], 
                function($scope, $timeout, nameService){

    nameService.index(); // console.log server
  
    $timeout(function(){
    
        nameService.index(); // console.log cached
      
    },3000)
    
    $timeout(function(){
    
        nameService.index(); // console.log cashed
      
    },6000)
  
}]);
```

It's all ok, first request fired `server`, other fired `cached`.
But if I send request without delay I send multiple requests to server. like:

```js
...
nameService.index(); // console.log server
nameService.index(); // console.log server
nameService.index(); // console.log server
...
```

They all fired `server`, but I need cached. I have multiple controllers with the same service. What the best way to send only one request to server?

Comment: Not a duplicate, as this is about caching the http response. The correct way would be to pass `{cache: true}` and not cache the promise anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to prevent the same requests to server?

Well, you can change `$http.get('/api/name')` to `$http.get('/api/name', {cache: true})`, this is actually built into Angular and works just fine.

This brings the interesting question of how to do it without using Angular's help for a generic promise - just as easy:

```
this._data = null;
this.index = function() { 
    return this._data || (this._data = $http.get('/api/name'));
}
```

That way, if it's cached it'll return the left hand side and if it's not it'll cache the right hand side.

The important part is that we *cached the promise and not the data*. That's the "trick" you've been missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in next way

```js
app.service('nameService', ['$q','$http', function($q, $http){
    var that = this;

    that.nameDeffered = null;

    this.index = function(){
        if (that.nameDeffered === null) {
            that.nameDeffered = $q.defer();
            $http.get('/api/name').success(
                function(response) {
                    // fired request to server
                    console.log('server');                        
                    that.nameDeffered.resolve(response.name);
                }
            );
        }

        return that.nameDeffered.promise;
    }
}]);
```

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: If author need to cache all respone which return $http.get('/api/name') we can write something like that in if statement that.nameDeffered = $http.get('/api/name'); But he want to cache only response.name. Thats why I created new deffered.

Comment: That's totally not needed - look at my answer for how it can be accomplished without it.

Comment: Yes, I looked at your answer, but your code do not do what original author code do. So if you use your service: nameService.index().success(function(result){console.log(result);}); you will see in console something like this: { name: 'bob', age: 24, email: 'example@example.com' }. But if you use author method you will see in console 'Bob'. This is the difference.

Comment: All it takes to do it would be to do `.then(x => x.name)` that's all.

Comment: Sure. But in some cases it may be crusial to return not all data for sake of incapsulation.

Comment: So `.then(x => x.name)` can be added to the code in my answer... creating a deferred is just misunderstanding promises.  Your code for example - does not handle server errors correctly.